How to enable IPv6 with bridge mode
We have a VDSL internet service (FTTB), and continuously have one of two issues - either double NAT or no IPv6.
Current Setup (No IPv6)

ASUS DSL-AC68U set to bridge mode.
TP-Link Archer AX6000 set to Dynamic IP.

My question would be what settings I need to use for IPv6 to be enabled and working on the TP-Link.
IPv6 works on the ASUS and TPLink when it is not in bridge mode (and IPv6 is set to Native), but it creates a Double NAT issue.
When the ASUS is in bridge mode the TPlink just does not seem to be able to resolve an IPv6 IP. I've tried setting the ASUS IPv6 to disabled, passthrough, and native, but nothing seems to 'go through' to the TPLINK if that makes sense.
If anyone can tell me the IPv6 settings for both the ASUS modem/router, and the primary TPLink router that'd be fantastic.

What WAN IPv6 options do you have in the Archer? Sometimes the correct one depends on ISP.

When the ASUS was not in bridge mode, the Archer was using Dynamic for IPv6 which worked.

Sure, but it worked when it was talking to the ASUS, not to the ISP, so that's not really relevant. What other WAN IPv6 options do you have in the Archer?

Also, what IPv6 WAN options or status do you see in the ASUS when it is not in bridge mode?
